# ASP.NET Without code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, .net-reflector

I've to make some changes on a precompile asp.net website that was build with an unknown framework (iron something...).
I have tried reflector to decompile the DLL from the page I want to change but since reflector doesn't know the dll is from a code behind aspx file it puts lots of unnecessary stuff and gives lots of errors and it's very difficult to fix...

Another approach I tried, since the page calls a method from a module, was to decompile the APP_Code dll, change the module and either rebuild the app_code project reflector creates or put the app_code files on the web site... Both give lots of errors also...

My last approach, and I still haven't tried this one, is to change the aspx file by adding a javascript that changes the form post page to a new page I'll add to the site (with code behind) and in that new page do whatever needs to be done.

My question is: is there any other approach to this problem and if not which one should I do? (I'm more leaned to the javascript and new page since the other ones I didn't manage to get them to work.. or is there a way to "say" to reflector that the dll is from a code behind aspx file?).

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: Must be [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) you're dealing with - maybe give [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) a go ... it usually does a decent job creating a working .net project from a dll.

Comment: Just found the name... Iron speed...